# Is there an alternative to the serverless-cloudformation-changesets? for serverless version 3

Tags: npm, aws-cloudformation, serverless, serverless-framework, dry-run

## Problem

Im just trying to deploy `serveless-cloudformation-changesets` on AWS codebuild
But the build failed because of versioning error

```
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
 
  The Serverless version (1.83.3) does not satisfy the "frameworkVersion" (3) in serverless.yml
```

Below details

### Cause

The `serveless-cloudformation-changesets` depends on serverless@1.83.3
https://github.com/trek10inc/serverless-cloudformation-changesets/issues/27
So executing delpoy with changesets opiton, I encounterd error

### code

#### buildspec-changeset.yml

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - npm install -g serverless
      - npm install --save serverless-cloudformation-changesets
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - DATE=$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
      - CHANGE_SET_NAME="sample_changeset_${DATE}"
  build:
    commands:
      - sls deploy --changeset $CHANGE_SET_NAME --stage $STAGE
```

#### serverless.yml

```
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:custom.defaultStage}
  region: ${opt:region, self:custom.defaultRegion}
```

### error logs

```
[Container] 2022/12/28 08:25:08 Entering phase INSTALL
[Container] 2022/12/28 08:25:08 Running command npm install -g serverless
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated superagent@7.1.6: Please downgrade to v7.1.5 if you need IE/ActiveXObject support OR upgrade to v8.0.0 as we no longer support IE and published an incorrect patch version (see https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/1731)

added 406 packages, and audited 407 packages in 19s

66 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

[Container] 2022/12/28 08:25:28 Running command serverless --version
Framework Core: 3.26.0
Plugin: 6.2.2
SDK: 4.3.2

...

[Container] 2022/12/28 08:26:07 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2022/12/28 08:26:07 Running command serverless --version
Running "serverless" from node_modules
Serverless: Deprecation warning: bin/serverless is deprecated, use bin/serverless.js instead
            More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#BIN_SERVERLESS
Framework Core: 1.83.3 (local)
Plugin: 3.8.4
SDK: 2.3.2
Components: 2.34.9

[Container] 2022/12/28 08:26:08 Running command serverless deploy --changeset $CHANGE_SET_NAME --s $STAGE --verbose
Running "serverless" from node_modules
Serverless: Deprecation warning: bin/serverless is deprecated, use bin/serverless.js instead
            More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#BIN_SERVERLESS
 
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
 
  The Serverless version (1.83.3) does not satisfy the "frameworkVersion" (3) in serverless.yml
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              16.15.1
     Framework Version:         1.83.3 (local)
     Plugin Version:            3.8.4
     SDK Version:               2.3.2
     Components Version:        2.34.9
```

## Question

- Is there an alternative to the serverless-cloudformation-changesets? for serverless version 3.

## My Idea

- If there wasnt an alternative, I will change serverless.yml with serverlessv2 or v1.

I checked the latest version of serveless-cloudformation-changesets.
But the library has not maintained since 3 years ago.
cf. https://github.com/trek10inc/serverless-cloudformation-changesets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this bug in the morning and decided to fork `serverless-cloudformation-changesets` and update it for [V3](https://github.com/astuyve/serverless-cloudformation-changesets-v3).

It's now published: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-cloudformation-changesets-v3

It's a drop in replacement, you simply need to run `serverless plugin install -n serverless-cloudformation-changesets-v3`, and the rest should work.

Comment: I really appreciate your work. I'll check if the changesets work well at my project!!

Comment: Great! Let me know how it goes. Feel free to upvote the comment and accept the answer if the library helps. Thanks!